# swift LLDB produces correct results, but different results from code execution

Tags: swift

I'm experiencing a weird behavior...

In short - running this command (on a `Range<Index>` ) within an application code

```
currIndexPlaceA = a!.startIndex.successor()..<newText.endIndex;
```

is ignored...

When I set a breakpoint after this command, and run `po a` in the debug window (lldb), I get:

> ▿ Optional>   ▿ Some : Range(39..<44)
>       - startIndex : 39
>       - endIndex : 44

while `po currIndexPlaceA` is:

> ▿ Range(5..<54)
>     - startIndex : 5
>     - endIndex : 54

it is clear that startIndex should have been higher than 39!

but, running the same command through the lldb window:

```
expr currIndexPlaceA = a!.startIndex.successor()..<newText.endIndex;
```

results in (`po currIndexPlaceA`):

> ▿ Range(40..<54)
>     - startIndex : 40
>     - endIndex : 54

What's going on here?????

If you want to debug my full function.. it's kind of a headache - it's a sort of xml parser...

I test it with text: `<id><id></id><id/><id /><id><id /><id/><id></id></id></id>`

and tagName: `id`

```
func getTagContent(text : String, tagName : String) -> [String!]!{
        // Extracts reply
        var newText = text;
        var currProcessing = text;
        var retVal = [String!]();
        while (newText != ""){
            let rangeFirst = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName, options: [], range: nil, locale: nil);
            if let actrange = rangeFirst
            {
                newText = newText.substringFromIndex(actrange.startIndex.advancedBy(tagName.characters.count + 1));

                let rangeEndFirstTag = newText.rangeOfString(">");
                if let actRangeEndFirstTab = rangeEndFirstTag {
                    let distToCloseTag = newText.startIndex.distanceTo(actRangeEndFirstTab.startIndex)
                    if (distToCloseTag == 0 || (distToCloseTag > 0 && newText[actRangeEndFirstTab.startIndex.predecessor()] != "/")) {
                        newText = newText.substringFromIndex(actRangeEndFirstTab.startIndex.advancedBy(1));

                        var currIndexPlaceA = newText.startIndex..<newText.endIndex;
                        var currIndexPlaceB = newText.startIndex..<newText.endIndex;
                        var a = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);
                        if a == nil {a = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);}
                        var b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);
                        if b == nil {b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);}

                        while (a != nil && b != nil && b?.startIndex < a?.startIndex){
                            let txt = newText.substringFromIndex(b!.endIndex);
                            var closedTag = false;
                            if let tmpRagne = txt.rangeOfString(">"){
                                if (tmpRagne.startIndex > txt.startIndex){
                                    if (txt[tmpRagne.startIndex.predecessor()] == "/"){
                                        closedTag = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            if closedTag{
                                currIndexPlaceB = b!.startIndex.successor()..<newText.endIndex;
                                var b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);
                                if b == nil {b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);}
                            }
                            else{
                                currIndexPlaceA = a!.startIndex.successor()..<newText.endIndex;
                                currIndexPlaceB = b!.startIndex.successor()..<newText.endIndex;

                                var a = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);
                                if a == nil {a = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);}
                                var b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);
                                if b == nil {b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);}
                            }
                        }
                        if a == nil { return nil; }


                        currProcessing = newText.substringToIndex(a!.startIndex);
                        retVal.append(currProcessing);
                        newText = newText.substringFromIndex(a!.startIndex.successor());
                        if let lastRange = newText.rangeOfString(">"){
                            newText = newText.substringFromIndex(lastRange.endIndex);
                        }
                        else {
                            return nil;
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        newText = newText.substringFromIndex(actRangeEndFirstTab.startIndex.successor());
                        retVal.append(nil);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }


        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: BTW, Swift does not use `;` to mark the end of a code line.

Comment: It allows it syntax wise , I like using it since I use 4 different languages throughout my day, and not putting it is weird for me .. This should not be the problem...

Comment: P.s. I also, usually , put conditions in parentheses, although apple does not recommend to , weirdly, and in some scenarios it can't compile it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the offending code.

```
currIndexPlaceA = a!.startIndex.successor()..<newText.endIndex;
currIndexPlaceB = b!.startIndex.successor()..<newText.endIndex;
var a = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);
```

A definite bug is the shadowing of `a` and `b` declared outside the `while` loop with the `var a` and `var b` in this `else` block. As for your LLDB problem, make absolutely sure that you have stopped on the line where `currIndexPlaceB` is set and not on or after where `var a` is set. Make sure all optimizations have been turned off as that may be causing code placement to be shuffled.

---

(Question writer... Adding code edits which solved the issue)

I'm adding here the final code, with additional bugs fixed (so if someone wants to get tags from xml - you'll have a copy-paste).
When debugging initially - I did't understand what was going on so I started using `endIndex` instead of `startIndex` etc.

```
func getTagContent(text : String, tagName : String) -> [String!]!{
    // Extracts reply
    var newText = text;
    var currProcessing = text;
    var retVal = [String!]();
    while (newText != ""){
        let rangeFirst = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName, options: [], range: nil, locale: nil);
        if let actrange = rangeFirst
        {
            newText = newText.substringFromIndex(actrange.startIndex.advancedBy(tagName.characters.count + 1));

            let rangeEndFirstTag = newText.rangeOfString(">");
            if let actRangeEndFirstTab = rangeEndFirstTag {
                let distToCloseTag = newText.startIndex.distanceTo(actRangeEndFirstTab.startIndex)
                if (distToCloseTag == 0 || (distToCloseTag > 0 && newText[actRangeEndFirstTab.startIndex.predecessor()] != "/")) {
                    newText = newText.substringFromIndex(actRangeEndFirstTab.startIndex.advancedBy(1));

                    var currIndexPlaceA = newText.startIndex..<newText.endIndex;
                    var currIndexPlaceB = newText.startIndex..<newText.endIndex;
                    var a = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);
                    if a == nil {a = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);}
                    var b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);
                    if b == nil {b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);}

                    while (a != nil && b != nil && b?.startIndex < a?.startIndex){
                        let txt = newText.substringFromIndex(b!.startIndex);
                        var closedTag = false;
                        if let tmpRagne = txt.rangeOfString(">"){
                            if (tmpRagne.startIndex > txt.startIndex){
                                if (txt[tmpRagne.startIndex.predecessor()] == "/"){
                                    closedTag = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if closedTag{
                            currIndexPlaceB = b!.endIndex..<newText.endIndex;
                            b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);
                            let tmpb = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);
                            if (b == nil || (tmpb != nil && tmpb?.startIndex < b?.startIndex)) {b = tmpb;}
                        }
                        else{
                            currIndexPlaceA = a!.endIndex..<newText.endIndex;
                            currIndexPlaceB = b!.endIndex..<newText.endIndex;

                            a = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);
                            let tmpa = newText.rangeOfString("</" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceA, locale: nil);
                            if (a == nil || (tmpa != nil && tmpa!.startIndex < a?.startIndex))  {a = tmpa;}
                            b = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + ">", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);
                            let tmpb = newText.rangeOfString("<" + tagName + " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: currIndexPlaceB, locale: nil);
                            if (b == nil || (tmpb != nil && tmpb?.startIndex < b?.startIndex)) {b = tmpb;}
                        }
                    }
                    if a == nil { return nil; }


                    currProcessing = newText.substringToIndex(a!.startIndex);
                    retVal.append(currProcessing);
                    newText = newText.substringFromIndex(a!.startIndex.successor());
                    if let lastRange = newText.rangeOfString(">"){
                        newText = newText.substringFromIndex(lastRange.endIndex);
                    }
                    else {
                        return nil;
                    }

                }
                else{
                    newText = newText.substringFromIndex(actRangeEndFirstTab.startIndex.successor());
                    retVal.append(nil);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }


    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Good catch!! I'd might not notice it since I was in front of computers for way too long... I'll confirm it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: regarding the LLDB - I stopped on that command line, executed it, and immediately after checked it... I have no explanation for that one, but since the problem is solved it's not that important for me any more (I assume it's optimizations, since the debugger ran all around...) THANK YOU!!